# JS return false when expression is true

Tags: javascript

I like to, and often use

```
return this || that
```

Now I get a true or false value from the db and when true I'd like to return false, and when false return an element, like so:

```
$('.orderDetailPanelLeft').append(function () {
    return !(!json.controls.download) ||
        $('<div>')
        .addClass('subPanel')
        .text('Download Results')
});
```

No matter how I add !, !(!, !(!! it returns true or (incorrectly) the element. I realize there is a simple "if" solution, so please don't offer that. I would like to return false when json.controls.download is true using the this || that syntax.

How can I write this so that either false or the div is returned in the "return" statement?

Comment: To be honest, your code doesn't look very readable. What is the issue with the simple "if" solution?

Comment: `||` will *never* return a falsey value from its left operand. That's how it works. When the left operand is falsey, it evaluates the right operand and returns its result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can abandon your abiding love for `||`, but still reeeeally want to go `if`-free:

```
$('.orderDetailPanelLeft')
    .append(function () {
        return json.controls.download ? false :
            $('<div>')
                .addClass('subPanel')
                .text('Download Results');
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it. @Derek you are correct about readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
return !json.controls.download && $('<div>')
                                      .addClass('subPanel')
                                      .text('Download Results');
```

This will work for your case if you don't want absolutely any variant of `if` including ternary operators. (or you simply hate the keyword `false` either case.)

For better readability you should prefer [Paul Roub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171149/283863).

`&&` is the opposite of `||` in [short-circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is just impossible because the `||` operator returns the first operand when it is evaluated to `true`, and the second operand if the first operand is evaluated to `false`.

Thus, no matter what you set as first operand, as long as it is a boolean value evaluated to `true` you will get that boolean value and not the element.

What you actually need is the `&&` operator, as suggested by Derek. With the `&&` operator you can get the second operand when the first operand is evaluated to true.